# Erro de sintaxe Visualg (Portugol)

Tags: sintaxe, visualg, portugol

Ao colocar o código desta forma e inserir estes dados "Faltas = 0 Provas = 5, 9, 7.2 Trabalho = 10.5 Idade = 15 Resultado = Reprovado", o mesmo da erro na hora de compilar, apresenta erro de sintaxe no "Result <- Reprovado"

```
var

Notafim, Faltas, nota1, nota2, nota3: Real

Idade, notatrab, Media, Peso1, Peso2: Real

Result, Reprovado: Caractere

inicio
// Seção de Comandos

Escreva ("Digite o número de faltas: ")
Leia (Faltas)

Escreva ("Digite a nota da primeiroa prova: ")
Leia (nota1)

Escreva ("Digite a nota da segunda prova: ")
Leia (nota2)

Escreva ("Digite a nota da terceira prova: ")
Leia (nota3)

Escreva ("Digite a nota do trabalho final: ")
Leia (notatrab)

Limpatela

Se (nota1>nota2) e (nota2>nota3) entao
   Media <- (nota1+nota2) / 2
Senao
   Se(nota1>nota2) e (nota2<nota3) entao
      Media <- (nota1+nota3) / 2
   Senao
      Media <- (nota2+nota3) / 2
   Fimse
Fimse

Se Faltas < 5 entao
   Peso1 <- 3
Senao
   Se (Faltas > 5) e (Faltas < 10) entao
      Peso1 <- 2
   Senao
      Peso1 <- 1
   Fimse
Fimse

Se Idade <= 17 entao
   Peso2 <- 1
Senao
   Se Idade >= 18 <= 50 entao
      Peso2 <- 2
   Senao
      Peso2 <- 3
   Fimse
Fimse

Notafim <- Media * Peso1 + notatrab * Peso2

Se Notafim <= 50 entao
   Result <- Reprovado
Senao
   Se (Nofim > 50) e (Notafim < 70) entao
      Result <- Regular
   Senao
      Se (Nofim > 70) e (Notafim < 80) entao
         Result <- Bom
      Senao
         Se (Nofim > 80) e (Notafim < 90) entao
            Result <- Muito Bom
         Senao
            Result <- Excelente
         Fimse
      Fimse
   Fimse
Fimse

Escreval
Escreval ("Este foi o resultado do aluno",Result)
Escreval
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Observe que você declarou a variável `Result` como caractere, portanto ela terá que receber um 'valor' caractere, note que `Result <- Reprovado` é diferente de `Result <- "Reprovado"`

**Observação**: Cuidado a declarar variáveis com letras Maiúsculas e minúsculas isto poderá ser um problema no futuro!

**Observação 2**: Retirei a variável "Reprovado", acredito que você estava tentando declara-la como caractere para ter resolver o erro de sintaxe.

Seu código corretamente ficará assim:

```
Var
// Seção de Declarações das variáveis

Notafim, Faltas, nota1, nota2, nota3: Real

Idade, notatrab, Media, Peso1, Peso2: Real

Result : Caractere


Inicio

// Seção de Comandos

Escreva ("Digite o número de faltas: ")
Leia (Faltas)

Escreva ("Digite a nota da primeiroa prova: ")
Leia (nota1)

Escreva ("Digite a nota da segunda prova: ")
Leia (nota2)

Escreva ("Digite a nota da terceira prova: ")
Leia (nota3)

Escreva ("Digite a nota do trabalho final: ")
Leia (notatrab)

Limpatela

Se (nota1>nota2) e (nota2>nota3) entao
   Media <- (nota1+nota2) / 2
Senao
   Se(nota1>nota2) e (nota2<nota3) entao
      Media <- (nota1+nota3) / 2
   Senao
      Media <- (nota2+nota3) / 2
   Fimse
Fimse

Se Faltas < 5 entao
   Peso1 <- 3
Senao
   Se (Faltas > 5) e (Faltas < 10) entao
      Peso1 <- 2
   Senao
      Peso1 <- 1
   Fimse
Fimse

Se Idade <= 17 entao
   Peso2 <- 1
Senao
   Se Idade >= 18 <= 50 entao
      Peso2 <- 2
   Senao
      Peso2 <- 3
   Fimse
Fimse

Notafim <- Media * Peso1 + notatrab * Peso2

Se Notafim <= 50 entao
   Result <- "Reprovado"
Senao
   Se (Nofim > 50) e (Notafim < 70) entao
      Result <- "Regular"
   Senao
      Se (Nofim > 70) e (Notafim < 80) entao
         Result <- "Bom"
      Senao
         Se (Nofim > 80) e (Notafim < 90) entao
            Result <- "Muito Bom"
         Senao
            Result <- "Excelente"
         Fimse
      Fimse
   Fimse
Fimse

Escreval
Escreval ("Este foi o resultado do aluno",Result)
Escreval

Fimalgoritmo
```

Comment: Entendo, tinha me esquecido dessa condição, obrigado.

Comment: Valide a resposta  para 'resolver ' sua pergunta

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour